# Java Hibernate: Persist automatically after setting a field

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In one of the Rest controllers of my spring app, an instance of an entity gets loaded from the db, a field of it is changed through calling `setXX` method on that entity and finally it's saved back to the db .

I wonder if it is possible to update this instance in the database automatically after each call to its `setXX` methods. I know that performance-wise it is not ideal, but it would work for me in some cases.

**Edit 1**

This is a test code where I'm saving/loading the entity. I call the following helper method in a util class to save user details to the db:

```
public CustomUserDetails createUser(String username, String name, String description, String imageId) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName(name);
        user.setDescription(description);
        user.setImageId(imageId);
        CustomUserDetails userDetails = new CustomUserDetails(username,
                DUMMY_PASSWORD, true, true, true, true,
                AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));
        userDetails.setUser(user);
        userDetailsRepository.save(userDetails);
        return userDetails;
    }
```

And in the test, I get the `User` instance by calling `getUser` on the returned value from this method. I `setXX` some values, but it's not persisted.

Comment: Your entity will automatically get saved in Database if you are calling the "setter" method from within a method that has "Transactional" annotation.
Usually we do it on Service layer.

Answer (score 4):

*Following the code excerpt addition*

```
User user = new User();
```

This is not a Managed entity.. You'll need to persist it and/or retrieve it from DB for your follow-up setter calls to be persisted (assuming Transaction is still on).

---

As long as the Entity is in the **Managed/Persistent** state then ([as per the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html_single/#d0e1739))

> any changes will be automatically detected and persisted when the
>   persistence context is flushed. There is no need to call a particular
>   method to make your modifications persistent.

Also as it's commented, within a Spring `@Transactional` method, fetching an Entity (therefore being in the **Managed/Persistent** state) followed directly by a setter property call will result in persisting the property.

Comment: I call the setter method within a test code which is not Transactional.

Comment: how are you fetching the entity during your test?